# Different listeners for each notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here's my code below,

```
var opt1 = {type: "basic",title: "Teva Noti1",message: "Don't click me!",iconUrl: "icon-phone.png"}
chrome.notifications.create("noti1",opt1,function(notificationId){
    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId){
        alert("test1")
    })
});

var opt2 = {type: "basic",title: "Teva Noti2",message: "Don't click me!!!",iconUrl: "icon-phone.png"}
chrome.notifications.create("noti2",opt2,function(notificationId){
    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId){
        alert("test2")
    })
});
```

I want to do different actions for each notifications. In my code, both alerts popped when I clicked any one of the notifications

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding just one listener to the notifications and check which one was clicked in the listener:

```
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId){
    if (notificationId == "noti1"){
        alert("test1");
    } else if (notificationId == "noti2"){
        alert("test2");
    });
```